# SharePoint Online - Create a site out of site template - feature issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, feature-activation

I was trying to archive a site saving it as site template. I wanted to create another site using this site template, here i ran in to the issue, [image: Problem applying web template]

On further investigation i understand that a hidden feature needs to be activated. Feature id is 3bc0c1e1-b7d5-4e82-afd7-9f7e59b60c0a.I dont have Powershell experience but I tried to activate feature with SharePoint Online Management Shell. I used [Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential admin@contoso.com] command to set up the connection but got an error. I have SharePoint admin rights and not Tenant admin. How can i activate the feature with my permission level?

I tried to deactivate all the features of my old site before saving it as a template and tried to create site of this template. I still run in to the same error.

Please suggest?

Thanks

Comment: That is the es-ES (Spanish) version of the SharePoint 2013 Routing Workflows. Are you moving to a different language site?

Comment: No, we are not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have problem with SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure. The Save site as template command is not supported and can cause problems on sites that use the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure. More information can be found here 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371B0F-00E0-4C49-A844-34759EBDD989?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: I was able to save the template. I am having issues when trying to create a new site using this template.

Comment: But did you use SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure on source site? If yes, it could have an impact, even if you switched if off before template save